# Is it grammatically correct to use 'now' third person past tense narration?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, third-person, narration

Here's my specific example:

> Puffing, Ralphie rested her elbows on the guardrail. Body Woman was now talking to a bald super spy.

(For context, Ralphie is on a balcony looking at Body Woman and the super spy.)

Is this grammatically correct for what is supposed to be a third person past tense narrative, or does it ruin it by bringing in the first tense? I don't want any 'it depends on the writer' nonsense. Just yes or no answers backed with arguments please. Also, if it is not grammatically correct, what should I replace 'now' with in a sentence like this in order to get the point across that there has been a change in the situation and now something is happening which was not happening before? The best answer gets a prize.

Comment: I wouldn't call "nonsense" the choices different writers might make at a given point in the narrative. Your specific example reflects a choice the writer made for who knows what reason. She or he could just as easily have chosen to say this: "While Ralphie rested her elbows on the guiardrail, puffing, Body Woman was talking to a bald super spy." Who's to say which choice is good, bad, or indifferent? I'm just sayin' . . .. Don

Comment: I think you deserve a prize for the phrase *'it depends on the writer' nonsense*. When would like to pick that up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "now" when talking about past events](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48879/using-now-when-talking-about-past-events)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a perfectly valid use of the word "now" and does not change the tense.

> [***Now***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/now)
>
> **(Definition) 1.5** (in a narrative or account of past events) at the time spoken of or referred to

Comment: Thank you! Here's your prize, the web serial that the example sentence was from: http://royalroadl.com/fiction/Chapter/101358.

Comment: ***slight bow*** Thank you, Thank you, I'm honored and humbled. I'd like to thank my parents... <and so on and so forth>

Comment: Good luck with the serial and happy writing.