# I have assigned it to you now

Tags: present-perfect

Is is correct to say "I have assigned it to you now"?

To me 'now' and 'I have' seem to be clashing in this context.

Comment: Do you feel that I have indicates the past?  I have two sentences here right now and not in the past.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "now" when talking about past events](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48879/using-now-when-talking-about-past-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. You could also simply say, "I have assigned it to you.".

The difference is that your version makes the implication that you just did it. There is nothing wrong regarding "I have" clashing with "now". I have is the present perfect form which requires a past participle verb (you used one: assigned). Now is an adverb which indicates it just happened. **Either of these are okay**:

*** "I have assigned it to you." (implies you assigned it as some point in the past)**

*** "I have assigned it to you now." (implies you have just assigned it, or did it very shortly ago)**

HINT: Adding the "now" at the end would usually be done in response to a query from someone (but doesn't have to be). For example User A sends User B a message saying, "I never got bug #4322 assigned to me.". User B responds and says, "Okay, I'm sorry, I have assigned it to you *now*.".